# Displaying of flight altitude in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, visualisation, display, extrude

I have seen Google Earth screen grabs of GPS bird trackers that show the altitude as a "curtain" extending down to ground level from the track. Is this possible in QGIS?

Comment: The profile tool in QGIS is what you are looking for https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/profiletool/

Comment: Have downloaded plugin but cannot connect it to height data.  I am importing the data as text delimited which includes height data.  I can see the tool connects with the layer because the colour of the line changes when tool is started but shows no height data.

Comment: Have been trying various options in the profile tool and eventually found an error message  "Active layer is not a profilable layer".  I cannot find any information on what would be an acceptable layer.

Comment: You will need a DEM of your area of interest https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOgpIe4R68E

Comment: That seems to be a very roundabout way to make a graph, I can do that directly from the data.  Still doesn't display what I had in mind or tell me what format the original file needs to be.

Answer (score 5):

QGIS has a 3D map view, but I couldn't get it to display a line with Z values. Here's a workaround using the 2.5 D renderer for polygons.

If you buffer a line, the 2.5D renderer setting will display the buffer as a "curtain." The problem is that the elevation of the top of the "curtain" is the same for the entire buffer. So you would need to split the buffer into many different sections, with a separate "elevation" attribute for each one. You'll need *a lot* of sections, many more than your original line has vertices. Here's a workflow for that:

1. `Densify` the line so that there are *many* vertices. The Z values will be interpolated from the nearest vertices (eg, if you add one vertex between two vertices whose Z values are 100 and 200, the new vertex will have a Z value of 150).
2. Run `Explode lines` to split the densified line into separate line segments. The exploded line layer will retain the interpolated Z values. **Note: if you don't want a full explanation, skip down to where it says "skip to here for a quick solution"**
3. Use the Field Calculator to add the Z values to the attribute table, with this expression: `z(start_point( $geometry))`
4. `Buffer` the exploded layer with a narrow buffer width (I used 1 m). This creates a polygon layer, to which we can apply a 2.5D style.
5. Apply a 2.5D style to the buffer layer. Choose the "z_value" field to control the height.

   [image]
6. Once you have the 2.5D rendering set up to your liking, convert it back to simple rendering to fine-tune the other aspects. This will convert the 2.5D rendering to two levels of geometry generated style, "building walls" and "building roofs". You can remove the first symbol level, the "building roofs," which is khaki-colored by default. The geometry generator expression for the "building walls" looks like this:

```sql
order_parts(
 extrude(
  segments_to_lines( $geometry ),
  cos( radians( eval( @qgis_25d_angle ) ) ) * eval( @qgis_25d_height ),
  sin( radians( eval( @qgis_25d_angle ) ) ) * eval( @qgis_25d_height )  ),
  'distance(
    $geometry,
    translate( @map_extent_center, 1000 * @map_extent_width * cos( radians( @qgis_25d_angle + 180 )),
    1000 * @map_extent_width * sin( radians( @qgis_25d_angle + 180 ))))',
 False)
```

You can simplify the geometry generator expression by replacing the `eval(variable)` terms with fixed values.

- Substitute 70 degrees (or whatever value you choose for *Angle* in the 2.5D renderer window) for `eval(@qgis_25d_angle)`. If you want, you can simplify it further by substituting the radian equivalent of that angle for the `radians()` term, eg substitute `1.22173` for `radians(70). I chose not to do this, because I find it easier to think of angles in degrees, and I might later want to input a different angle value.
- Substitute the z_value field for `eval(@qgis_25d_height)`.

  The simplified expression looks like this:

```sql
order_parts(
 extrude(
  segments_to_lines( $geometry ),
  cos( radians( 70 ) ) * "z_value",
  sin( radians( 70 ) ) * "z_value" ),
  'distance(
    $geometry,
    translate( @map_extent_center, 1000 * @map_extent_width * cos( radians(70 + 180)),
    1000 * @map_extent_width * sin( radians(70 + 180))))',
 False)
```

At this point, you may notice that the first term inside the `extrude` function is `segments_to_lines($geometry)`, which converts the polygon edges into line segments. But we actually already had line segments, back in step 2. We only created buffers because the 2.5D renderer requires them. We can cut out the middleman here. Substitute `$geometry` for `segments_to_lines($geometry)`, and use the modified expression on the *exploded* layer.

**Skip to here for a quick solution**

Paste this expression into a geometry generator style layer for the *exploded* layer (created in step 2):

```sql
order_parts(
 extrude(
  $geometry,
  cos( radians( 70 ) ) * "z_value",
  sin( radians( 70 ) ) * "z_value" ),
  'distance(
    $geometry,
    translate( @map_extent_center, 1000 * @map_extent_width * cos( radians(70 + 180)),
    1000 * @map_extent_width * sin( radians(70 + 180))))',
 False)
```

[image]

TIPS:

- Save frequently. 3D and 2.5D rendering may make QGIS crash.
- Once you have the workflow figured out, put it into a Graphical Processing Model. Then you can run the whole model in one step every time you want to convert a line into a "curtain."
- There are "steps" between every buffer section. The steps are nearly invisible where the vertical difference is small, but they're quite noticeable where the vertical difference is larger.

  - Using a smaller vertex density interval in step 1 would make the steps less noticeable.
  - Explode the line first, before densifying. Add a "slope" attribute based on how steep the line slope is. Line slope = `(z(start_point($geometry))-z(end_point($geometry)))/distance_to_vertex( $geometry,1)`. When you densify, use the "slope" attibute to control the vertex density, so you have more vertices along line segments with a steeper slope.

A note about the starting data type:

This method starts with data in the form of a line layer with altitude stored as Z coordinates of the vertices. If your data is point coordinates in a text file, follow these steps to convert it.

- Import your text file from the layer menu > add layer > add delimited text layer. It should import as a point layer. If the coordinates are in latitude and longitude, choose EPSG:4326 as the CRS and remember that latitude is the Y coordinate and longitude is the X coordinate.
- Use the tool `set Z value` to add the "altitude" attribute to the points as a Z value.
- Use the tool `points to path` to connect the points into a line. This tool requires that the points had a field that defines what order they should be connected in. If the points have a time or date field you can use that.

It should be possible to directly use the text file in this method. You would need to write an expression that draws a line from the current point to the next point, something like `make_line($geometry, #next point#)` except with an actual function to get the next point. Substitute it for the first `$geometry` term in the geometry generator expression.

Comment: it is fabulously!

Comment: I didn't expect such a detailed answer, exactly what I had in mind and a very good tutorial.  Thank you csk.

Comment: Have been trying to implement this and nothing seemed to be the same, then I realised the solution uses QGIS 2.  Still poking around trying to find a workable solution with QGIS 3 Madeira

Comment: I wrote this answer using QGIS 3.

Comment: I have just come back to this and trying to make it work, with no success.  I think I may be starting with the wrong layer type.  I am using a  text file with the headings;-Date/Time,Lat,Lon,Altitude.  Should it be converted to another format before trying the solution outlined?  When I highlight the layer and open "densify" the layer name is not there and I can't enter it.  If I point it to the original text file it says the file is not found.  I tried using points to path and then densify but after conversion the layer has lost the altitude parameter.  I will keep trying but not hopefull.

Comment: You're right, the issue is the starting data type. I'll add a note to my answer explaining how to convert your data into a line with Z values.

Comment: I realise now this is beyond my knowledge and capabilities at the moment but will keep trying to work through it.

Comment: Fair enough. This is a very complicated workaround, because QGIS unfortunately doesn't have a simple way to do what you wanted. The 2.5D and 3D capabilities are still fairly limited in QGIS.

Comment: Have come back to this, I can import the text file and specify the z value as the altitude but when I use “points to path” the resulting layer has no altitude attribute when you look at layer properties, just a begin and end.  Also if I specify “Directory for text output” the height attribute is missing from this file.  I must be missing something but can’t figure out where I’m going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the *Qgis2threejs* plugin?  Very easy to use!  A screenshot of a simple example is below, and you can rotate the actual output [here](http://truenorthgis.org/qgis_examples/3d_flightline/index.html).

The display is the initial portion of an actual Gulfstream III flight, departing Deadhorse, Alaska on August 16, 2014, climbing to the northwest, then turning southerly at a cruising altitude of 40,000 feet. Altitude is depicted by the "curtain" height, and airspeed is symbolized categorically with color.

[image]

Comment: how did you import the flight data into qgis?  If try to import a KML file qgis seem to ignore the altitude fields.

Comment: My data started as *Flightaware* points, which I then converted into line segments, wherein each segment contained attributes for flight id, begin time, end time, altitude, and airspeed.  Since you seem to be having a separate problem (KML import error), I suggest you search for that topic, and post a separate question if no solution already exists.