# Producing Space-Time Cube in QGIS

Tags: qgis, cartography, visualisation, spatio-temporal-data, space-time-cube

Although I have seen many examples about doing this at ArcGIS Desktop, I am still trying to find a how to using QGIS. What I want to do is something like the image below.

[image: example]

Comment: You could probably manipulate the 2.5D polygon style into doing that.

Comment: @csk thanks for replying, I would appreciate if you could elaborate more on polygon manipulation.

Comment: It wouldn't be manipulating polygons, it would be manipulating the 2.5D polygon *renderer*, which is designed for displaying buildings. You would set up a 2.5d style, which creates a geometry generator style. Then you would need to make some serious changes to the geometry generator *expression* to introduce your data fields and add the bar graph. As far as I know it's never been done before, so it would be a lot of work in uncharted territory. I expect it would take at least two full days to accomplish. Good luck and please post a new question if you get partway into it and get stuck.

Comment: @csk I want to thank you very much by your reply. It is exactly what I hope to find at stack. I'm still a beginner on QGIS and although it will take me much more than 2 days to learn and implement the solution, now I have a clear path to follow.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. I did something similar (but for a different purpose) here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337207/displaying-of-flight-altitude-in-qgis-3-4/337315?r=SearchResults&s=1|18.2428#337315 As you can see it's not an easy approach, and I think your desired bar graph outcome will be even more complicated. It seems possible though. Please post your solution as an answer to your own question when you figure it out.

Answer (score 11):

One option to do this would be by modifying your data and visualizing it with the excellent [qgis2threejs](https://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/en/docs/) plugin. The idea is to turn your your time to Z coordinates. I tried it out with two GPX tracks I had. After adding the files to QGIS, I ran **Set Z value algorithm**, where I entered the following expression as the Z value:

```
second("time"-minimum("time"))
```

[image]

The expression takes the timestamp (stored in my data in a field called "time") from each point feature and compares it to the minimum timestamp in the whole layer. This calculation results in to an interval data type, which can be converted to integer seconds with the *second* function. For this to work with **your** data, you might have to use minutes or hours or use some kind of a multiplier.

Next up you should install the qgis2threejs plugin via the plugins dialog. If you have data with Z coordinates in your project it should detect that automatically and you can visualize the results with additional data and a basemap if you want. I also merged the layers and added a extruded polygon from the bounding box as the "cube":

[image: qgis2threejs preview]

- Downside: really hard to build a legend for the space-time cube.
- Upside: you'll have an **interactive** space-time cube and you can use all the cool functionalities in qgis2threejs to make the end result more informative.